# how to convert this to this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  have a problem with pandas dataframe. I want to modify my dataframe. Columns name is "cascade". How can I edit it. If you solve problems like this please help me to solve this issue or any ideas for this.

From this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: Please share the code you are using so we can better help you. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: Please do not attach dataframes as pictures, add them to your question as code (for example `df.to_dict()`). What are the data types before and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `cascade` column looks like this:

```
["['(E12)', '(E14)']", "['(E81)', '(E82)']"]
```

To convert it into:

```
[['(E12)', '(E14)'], ['(E81)', '(E82)']]
```

You can use:

```
df['cascade'] = df['cascade'].str.strip('[]').str.replace("'", "").str.split(', ')
```

**Explanation**:

- First the [.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor is used to transform the `pandas.core.series.Series` object to a `pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods` object in order to apply vectorized string operations to the `cascade` column of the dataframe
- Then [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) is called to strip the brackets from each element of the series,
- The previous `.strip()` returned a new `pandas.core.series.Series` object which we need to convert into a new `pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods` object in order to apply the next `.replace()` call.
- Similarly, for the final `.str.split(', ')`